# Redirect stderr doesn't show python input

Tags: bash, python, io-redirection, python3, stderr

I am running the following command on the terminal:

```
python -c "input('Message')" 2> log
```

but the `Message` doesn't appear on the screen. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these circumstances, and in spite of what [the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), [Python writes the prompt to standard error](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/46221) — so it is sent to `log`.

Comment: The documentation should be updated.

Comment: @adosar I believe the proper channel to report this is an email to docs@python.org.

Comment: @doneal24 as the links in my answer show, it’s already been reported and extensively discussed.